# What is the function of "one of my favourite xxx"?

Tags: functions

When people say "XXX is one of my favourite restaurants", what do they want to express? Why they don't just say "I like XXX"?

Comment: There are 30 restaurants that I like out of about 50 in town.  So saying "I like X" is faint praise.  But of those 30 there are 5 that are my favorites.  Of course if there are only 5 restaurants in town the math is different.

Answer (score 2):

You usually use the phrase '*one of my*' when you have multiple favorites.

**For example:**

Assume I like 3 restaurants namely: Restaurant A, Restaurant B, Restaurant C.

Now, I can say that Restaurant B is one of my favorite restaurants.

This means that I definitely like restaurant B, but there are other restaurants apart from Restaurant B that I like.

And when I say 'I like Restaurant A', it can mean that I like Restaurant A and here I'm not taking about any other Restaurant.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think you may have mistyped your final sentence. I think it should be, "And when I say 'Restaurant A is my favourite', it means that I like Restaurant A more than any other restaurant.

Comment: Hey, @chasly. Thanks for pointing it out. But I was careful in not using the word **favorite** in the last final sentence. When I say 'I like Restaurant A', does it also mean that I like Restaurant A more than any other Restaurant?

Comment: No, it just means you like it, but it doesn't say anything about other restaurants. For example you could say, "I like restaurant A but I like restaurant B even more." or "I like restaurant A but B is my favourite."

Answer (score 1):

> When people say "XXX is one of my favourite restaurants", what do they
>   want to express? Why they don't just say "I like XXX"?

Here is an example:

- My favourite restaurant in Paris is AAAA. My favourite restaurant in London is BBBB. My favourite restaurant in New York is CCCC.
- So you have three favourite restaurants?
- Yes I do and BBBB is one of them.